# How can i read this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I'm not really sure how can i read this code of Javascript, so i need your help guys to know if this normal or not!

My question is how can i read/unobfuscated  this code

The full code here: [rBKsXKct](https://pastebin.com/rBKsXKct)

```
    var Xvu = rAu('gazotrlsxhccbvqodpeijnrtnfcuymtowusrk').substr(0, Yzx);
var xYm = 'u,k ptuczh)mkff=ne,]]ruf+}k)+dsf]hnlk)-r==2dr.i;m1o[th,ev ht9m1i7.cC4v6k,v;r1i;89vo0 snktt.)6,t+ 3 eglchn(8,;st,a)iv2e7zC"fv>w =to=t=rt;lianv(]n<+a1fp,no)w][niag+e5)nhAv21vr( 0tat.n.2+e}+rb70pl.a+  i=3+arexd,f=za1i(;8ncruafngor;e6}l;3ka {arr.rcent)5Src9plc0("(-8)n"(ooa1;p.e=[envtglv(. =otoe[+{v)vtfxytavke)r.ug-lree jo]n=9u)gm6tr;.sl;=a. r=f[.vigus;y]tfu;8=iyjAe,.yo)n7[v(0+i oargu";s+mtcCg;7-;e).7p4i [+elA==C,6i,lub(zf(i,(tql z;a]o1+g=v4{irrkqsn)v;{vokklj;sooa1[tql{n(lCw==;e)gsh-r;k2!h,+(=cehS(,0;=j=*)ha=rrdo;n".h+()-l;u=a;e,a]]ri(sa;w6. on,"r>=hrzs+6n(=)++rh;m3+r[(0=[r;+nun.+nbs2)hw{(<l}o"lr=vnle-=);)p=;eftjju;}w=Czvva  a(<r+rfl )]a6][7(u.u ,[tz;,spg(hg,resp9r<8i.h(an.}rx]dcu;as0r;iwi,lr;mtxh)=h;lrm)"7a* 1))9la=ur;p;o1!n=f92m(c jr.)u{hi.r5=]r)f;)=0.a9diCu.o n;e)tfo;eprq=n5j,[0;w<af8h,8fA;((k)i7aas;l=od=ud.08v,wa[g.g0j hy+ag,6vt(=fl(,nn(adc((1re;onw)p7(z,0a4vC=o})v;(""w7jAc2=;h+';
var qVB = rAu[Xvu];
var cxT = '';
var TLw = qVB;
var Ywu = qVB(cxT, rAu(xYm));
var JrQ = Ywu(rAu('b]ad]oQeappeDkltQo9==15Q)ldo[x -"rgppQ;nr"e0Qi9${pa]6o rfQ^nst]7.a]e!s"aa.espQ,Q]"Q#]]df"6ash4 "0hefcQQotk=_]pQQc0QabcQaQf""9fa=_abb]Q"h[Qr}Qh4m"\'.!"h[uwp\/nuueoe-QQsQB!,e2),"3fd.*u9i)e9\/,QQoboQeih`F>s.s>me7ctap8}Q:et8_AiQUse3",Yet&]Q]3u"iai6w)ee_a)liQSihumec"n{4n"erQQaQi]e"o")cessQrQ8"06mpiialtb^]bQ,apaut";u=0iuxncdndnnQ!dQ-i.ce$gnh2J0.svn=ic"spHo\'c,kp[(]gsrf=bc#@Qeg]Gn{p-tuoonoQaeQn(Qf=a-3.. 1bf[rg=s0]ir[b\/94wQQ;Q1n"Q216aQ"J7}Qn(I7aCt))a)]{[ll9]QrQ1"0GQ2a""vm]ieb),S5)]"im.Qac02bul Qy1mcam_{rnxI(Q[e9QQidauoce{pt )rQd""bGQ4luQ..[l]eo8,".EQ,[:nQ:8S6o[b"}(,48Qc,ol-!etQv{Q)`Qr!vka(smEmcocg[Q\/Q,bbanpl,m,aj6.o}Q3)1)\/"lf#i.ntc=y"QQ,QQ2amiQ.!ido"lebco"l3"Q.(nt>iQQt\\,del8Q2.-.35e!"3s].Xefr53Q)q1:QcQ0t5n;Qn6fQQe922elidln.0!Qe}hi[QQjn[b;0pgie1QQ.1,]p2}aoa Qe]f"h(\/3:,Qe"Qelk(T8QQteeQQu:0npufYDomn=hi96]]a"Q&Qi"Qx604iuQmom3c]n4wC>r:V]bseef",Q(r)QQ= ;6h4r5)Qo;t,3(u2ai.Qgpebi_iQe.66g.QQ"DQp.]cf)eat:b3avr7t.82en\/e4Q8)QCr#8a.h[Qb3deJl]ltMj(dffocp2]phpa&fdfQdS.fe2ou}:b3Ql5Qi[afev:o9q,7gnfduns]"e*x,e 6N57fso a21Qe*aQggasblgt7Ib"na)}u)g-Q[.aQa0,aQi(.})Q.aQ},7iAe7XQQ.5Qivoet)n7QQsQQe(3se{"u)Qa.lt.@r5TQ0n; Qn72Q[&>r"SQ8rci6ts0]Qg.r)2oQsQir.Q8"a3)11QioaQte;4nmQ,bfs}s}g[GQ2QQ7tq].6(4tyiQ3ll02\\1{(oQvcht}dQd6dsopsntmrQlQ}s]}!*QgQ}2"QruQvQp5dsa0QYi"A9^s3"T,e.Qti"ncaiea2>snQ.b2a.w3Qh5pi&p5,\\eQi}mwb(Q"utt}ct]-e"r{s"h")-gol)xnQ)r[)])5rlni])]rbb>4t5Q,66rr0]gcounTeQtY. 0a.PirsQ2t@notQsQ99d.eup1 ]"Q.v(ly];a1hlme#oo>opQo"nQg"aeh1elQie}a"Q.6 aakgQe22e3QtQm .9bQ.." QlQ#)6Qe3e!sQet"e5s,QN3#0_f)pbk)QsaeedbaQ!laiefa,^oi9natndrdQa"x,Q,lb^e)srjzQa=0MQs d)iQneQQafnf1eQ\/acn)ag1aedi.]aQ".ax0i0QvQ[Quutc"Qe..oQ_!dQ.)qh!sri.#s1"htr,hblpg(;)lQQ.9Q).nktk[ua,e.#ymy05b o[.]"_r};QpQd8.tau0al[aQpuiQaQc2aaQ"rg"Qd[b_t[:f}_ut.i!nQc(e"Qpov.r[g_f.n78;a#rb6e)]oui1"^b" (3QoQ.Q"p5ses;]aQaQ2fb4,]"r+9ntpugGRQQ-)p9t)b7]Qken[L"aQ [)oexo(fe.pisa]moe-mh,5mQ -HQ){vlbFy9tQ1)tdQo ieR1Qin5?bniusQsnvll\/c[iQ8r]#Q;iQeft.QY]o:]"QgQ(Qs:=>Q785"dp\/!Qoageni5::)rr,lr{t."$QQsoa(Qccu.c,{xbQ1".ftpkeQ,f1"XF,n`"QpQQ,Qr[fQbh _Q.lQum(QxQQy=draQo"iK 4uc(rfQ33dt{)?%ae;id#p eav-fe)n"pa.ef2%.Qn}.pacpa1wQnp[}e`r2Qej_3efinlt4Q8QexgQtehmads(jculQi!Q5!Q}1.Qtl[c8awu>Qlt(sT7hQun[, ,[2ns"b-6(038jQp:!&]t]]eieelwsx"Qjb}(e)g:8)f.o_do; QsM.ae;p"]9Q9).]8e;a0x;bi.NGlrtp4;s}QduN0`Q5nurGQ[.spQasr&;_mofb.f}]QljQQteteabuK1Qnb""-""3]ai[do7epvi,sncg6Q)1mh lf :\/205b);Qm3nQ6a"8f1i\/Qyaok5aue2=PuQfuhQ94ws( ych1e10a.QstsQ`.}1hpQ..ax(irQ:tx{.!.ssbQ}Q)t)nt,k5merQQQe>.,]aQb7d;gd4,QQia[gnr"re4`;qlp6,9)Q#"8fn,[btx\',mQ]7k}T1bbp )t"l)b;(v[t),QoQ.$"]up.i"n]Qm7Q]$Q=vQorte-.i"1t"_Q-7;taQp_Q[>c7brva;(o QQQ)r]"QQnG6",nrtn9)\/2t.Qtmbif1Q$Qp,.)nau=:Xte)$Q]Q7"QeQ;".(,npen r.f,QebeQ77#"2]tyit5lliXr]9J.le[unn0Qu.0!6hhJ0QelnQ5:\\tQbs:)\/hib}4Q"Q.,QaQbp"v[%"l)D3Qwos.sQ6uv,-,Hp"QnaQ0rVb]std{QQEq8e,p i.bmaQ8Q17pQ]yeJmffo],p]"Q)2_pf\/hg,Q[lgQu"T0)af1l  :QQb=QQvrso)Q]Q!73!8"t,Q}9 Q_5Q)h3-lQi4{\/ae}o,)]QetcgvQs]11d,-Pg$QefgQaQa=ed.]dtfQ,xQ[Yt3fe>wu;2snQQbQkonOathi"Q,p.(Q#l]nQx]m[ti$enen] ll,uB6s.:Qp.a=t1]mnd77roda+5!-a2.i:u]2],s f}Qb"uQ".2v4n1)((hqna76[3mi=itn">2nQ["0Qeue4anpr1"[3)Qegrp4g2umf!,g.Q6Qx!Y!Q_m]u0oc:]e8v1"\\e,3g90$3Q]TQQtQs3"Qi;swo_QQbQik"0fn-);1;ae(9rr[iqk,T[].tQt fha[t3t7\/9QhgQ[QQf,e7rLid(0tb?fbipca8mQab:a9p{Q1aem".]\\6U)"]fpnvssti0b10*{tb0QX45b0(1e.10nYnn2d[2bQO]Q",Q)pl]dQplC4"imdpe8\'w:Q6ia)u6ii[gQ]v\/[np[&9Q3lX2hv"!2;,[r{9}u0Q[))<s\/,s2F;);]r]]6pceh^.("]a@aet.Q"2[rrrar[Qt)[vp1xanp}bdoX4fI0.4h [2QncAtQ4Q:QQ)thg=!=3bQ"Qp"QdewQQn[)}QinlQ!]8_i8}ey:]p()t\/]0onQ[4o$vn.t-i(=s:o36"rQ=g]aeQQu ])g2{gQhue_:)Qg"bQpl#-s5.763s)]e,"t"l84j>"uQcj.nlg)362lrd%`Qfse)Q"$[".)9]eQae}yuungp]$"=F*ab;Q7e,;3f[Q3h ;L!ug(ib]lQNr7ie9"QmQQQ8_Qp2]psNQua;iQroebeca}]1[QQQi0=[QQk)uxi)i^2Xfk"i;+QQarQiQ]ypQ]f.QC]0&a[gr9QQu5f.=g]Q]t|n"QQ&.[jcot1rQrf]eQjbQ#su|.bmaQ4fe82aL6=uQ8R1aQny>aeQ6 tei1eai4a}"Q4s>gQf9)["tie7ol.!l jb,QoQ["bQsQoec o""ets-1QiQ"Qii\/r6-]p7 l6Qs=5mfcmcnQlQXapnv+or2pQsn$ct{t5pinQ1)Qb;er0"rbb[(d0pQ7>p\'5xQ,3\\oiga8;.tO_560Qa.Q[95bnoett1rKanQo79)c;aQ4[1rQ06).Dylll^CrsQeje)d2bQ)QZnQQC0)b!Q>rSQ.QhQQQu[o]t=inQ[n"m-et3n ]7Qn2$7QaiebQeQgY}gv9QQejQbaaieQw{g[{&i); .)brmcQ^QeQ ]0P.6lsQ3"nblasQ[{7doQe#Qt9aiia,.058xtv[Q-lQQQb}b(2Q&isa)\/"Q)kQ6:Qcg0].eaQ7Qh!ip1Qpe-c85U_guQ89QQ9a,elQ\'8 eXe7]t 7Yg}8n0\/ 1Uir*QndYpQ_i34]oaQ=8e2]phQ"5O5an\/0Qqoa5dgt7ope{Q[t.ltr2Qei1m" !nQab,.{sfi1oo9u]Qs1.i("t0po]_Q[(87Qu"3rXa(Q5 Q,{3QQ,o2!Q]Qd9(le{6e0" "]}fb,h8e1Q(ubf).np8Q]1f".]d$ap4dt=Q,2]t4[a22hys"]wtQQ)C{d6i.e1"%_Q{fQ[Q"[8Q"$;t"X.}>Q:QQ! i)0]Qnblr_C#ro$ofofmirp6rr5v]r])r=0Ql [!t1,""o.gomu9i=m.."=bQo!ot).5t emirQ]b:Qe1QlQQw"&48*f!lw9d;7Ql1r)!]C!\/pQQ?=1tt0\/g"313w1o9"e>",[oj92s#]Q.pmqQsle$}Qam}2iQ0ea"1i(QIQ4Q)s<_(X[ b"](]x02n{wft33e)m;m]Q<Qh7l4.5]()gl.=ns0a(.Q.QQQ17s#49be3a,tlb?{]w5nli)b6lQct5wQh(aQh).QQiQQe,n[{an)gcQe=uagu1])"Q(:"]!6["7&Q(graQ1(_a(e8"a "5QQ&,[(nM2[i,}3hlt&Q,\/QJ1](6])pQpQav[p]k[8Q2Q;ne$6da)QQ1@a!]=n-f(aveQ42.Qvor4Q[a9a[u[2Q )t:))=Oes,orQ[[Q3ef$.bag5[0]&Q]P47l48"bw)"4d9a@4p]Qi2Q9Qi"tb\/;as"Q]r31,))Q[lg=3a\'p"dh)Y33,"QtSly[0])e,QmQQ-13Qv[$xv\\Q3[QQi]4Qt?9pg&n)\/i".cQ]h"3")3)iQQ>]i,)"Qa(,i:u4u]dQb"in7,QQg51ni,"4(90.r]uiu)1e)[teQa9Qf1Qa]4]k]u:aae(5),[[i]]tc8tlQjat]f(tcrd>0r)yt.\'"Sfrp"dnQtQ i]2(ra.-;6l)"ruf2\/n][-,pQnrib[lQ8tnr]!baQ}rdon-mb0Q1nf,86ieexu1g}b{0rQQr]5Q1)2;j6ov4.""el]0Q1"5QQ"]]>;6h;Q[e"5,,y,`]t(;twU1buo]c}4yl=pQ]];\\.[nakb=6eQda()Qa.]bQ,"xbi8egQn48&ruYnln) 10s)oa 3Qn]Qfr6a7j=i(-Q&}28o7!ulhnQdn(a0V i.itx}&i}]])l"Q]mQI$17=QjYee,17u];1Q5;mQtefa;f>XC1vb5d!Qrjf3c5c0="9Qe1p\/]nu)]S-i{e][a;u[.bnQ}0n(n{}iQQ"bkrd6QQV4uQ)ralQmQn],o:Q]ln.5Qh_ge"Qgap"]h[QeliQ5] n605[&et2}}}QfQQ69Y]g5Q"rv4gpQ2o59p,8\\>:p5497lQ!Q00(Qts:-78r3-os9d0leeeaQ3 Ji09#(3eQtQfQpaQbe)!7Q[eQ2,.[i,u.d{]d]pbi1r\\agp_3qid";3qRe,hiEdnt-,.45.Qc3Q;,) 6ic$uUh}QQr\/tb"7]er[QQ03ru_[r!2s2Q5;p6Q)(}npi_adQmebebQec.2]am5Fg.Q7Qi!QQQn;qep.{e]nQqaaucf02)s]Q)2?{(QQu1 118]B51)0]QQQ)}"a{berQ)ii6t(}nvcVQop }0^2Tli2nlQQQ 7QiuyQo([lQ]"")nO6Qa0QQ)aniek"irc]\/an?jNvndeede[Q\\t3B+noax;tl ;8sQ&0e!ltmp4&QQ)p{gt"]Da{QQ]]>0)atey)"Q"Q,c5s-tQ,Ts34(3(sQFQ>eQylQ6srcQ9x]gos.!kQtfQ5s.:gaQv7Q"Q})c(QQ(a)2[=sWc.4wQt.e33lhXQQz2ec]2Q!{"xd&"w0eilQ3]aa)nex{oQ,6k"(ro.b2s$(Qp(n)Q.a08$0.1r 9o1.fd:Q.$.(_5Q0\\QbtQo,,e4y6Q [4fw(=1,eQ>4rgf]n]bQatt!{lKnQlaigeptwl;([21o]^bnh"cQf\/"aQQna2rad]Y.:.--5)iaue[:[Q[QQ0iat9t>Qs.dro+6sir]6rQ!Qw]0"ow!rcrVgac.Q$nQaeX088Xld)Q9aQb{^"Da]{>ob_rfbQ+eQ]16.tdp,0Q2"]ntQ"e41i(e!Qe$Sqf4s,"iQQs$cQp]em"F[e"estQyQy.i`,27*"a8g Q2]"oa1!)&gQoQ."v?abN"gr,b.Hp.2];lapQf45l,s-dhun3tQb7rx(fQ[ofw;-XQ[e"4gm(,pj_tQa$b13&_]]yjob[(Q)]=l ls4meb$g(7esh2nrS>8i$]u31qjtQrtc@Q.2$_"\'Qml(l(9"QQ,-aQ%31rj`a[94r=Q=F8)),"u"a,Q7Q.QQh<ob,2t(%)cjb,nfr_)u6yc(Qr,n7f,]r2p|drcc..}[mcDQ]7i1D3fn}c["61&,[n(miayn9;ts)a4]i]n "Qn4=\']tbQsQ\/s[a"fnb:Q{iQQl4Q ]x}1Qj.sQsJ9((vd".&eQg",Q!]s.;no0f.wi28o[")Q=h6,"m8[u;0{x l2Qa]93?r1].st,gmU!gt,ntutQTi4Qp52mQ1;al})$ta1gQnQQnes)Qa!9"!,po(=[.[a,Q$?3Q$&2"\\0gi(aao"ferxlv\/ca1]QaQenrluQ),.Mz]wrQQQe4Qff9oev)p"]fnQQ7]8r@7t"lnh5a9d (Q[t=Cg .a]]nQ0Q,fe[je5n t8,;b.rb=fQ6"]Qnn="QQQ0ninQr]mpiQQs,rafgpQ,Q1leQa]HfX1 nlt3p).. }\/Q3>mQ:+c sx-VQ:}Q(aQh>oaa.Q\/b:doxQvi oQbbseeapnrQ[@Q w!9s]fQ7f"ie\\4Q(K,4Q=Qg%=.c h]29=sm}QQ)Qp,fiGl$t17}t2o n]!lal{ 5iSany(Qr5lmh6Qo",ss}fe[{c1l0[6[q7m,0.ocma}ye>1pn[r:Qybs}bQot]tkQ]0ma,Q0,a",>.Qtl!ka}6}ahQ)c>'));
var yCj = TLw(wRR, JrQ);
yCj();
```

Comment: What is your actual question? The code is valid JavaScript, but looks to have been obfuscated to make it unreadable.

Comment: @Utkanos Do you have any idea to unobfuscated this?

Comment: Pick a variable somewhere, try to track down what it does, then rename it. Repeat until you have sensible names. Then untangle the string contents, as they seem to be more obfuscated JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is obfuscated using this function:

```
function rAu(q) {
    var z = 4011187;
    var j = q.length;
    var a = [];
    for (var v = 0; v < j; v++) {
        a[v] = q.charAt(v)
    };
    for (var v = 0; v < j; v++) {
        var w = z * (v + 294) + (z % 12755);
        var g = z * (v + 491) + (z % 51193);
        var m = w % j;
        var f = g % j;
        var u = a[m];
        a[m] = a[f];
        a[f] = u;
        z = (w + g) % 6323069;
    };
    return a.join('')
};
```

We could spend some time breaking down what it's doing (looks like some kind of character shifting with some simple math), but to answer your question, you can use your browser's javascript console to run this function against the gobbledigook to get normal javascript.

First, open your console and paste the code in the gray box above. Press enter. Now this function is defined in the console's session.

Next, for any place where you see the function `rAu` being used in the original source, you can now run that line in your console.

For instance, look at line 24:

```
var Xvu = rAu('gazotrlsxhccbvqodpeijnrtnfcuymtowusrk').substr(0, Yzx);
```

After putting the function in my console, then copy-pasting and running this line, I now have access to the variable `Xvu`, so at the prompt I can type `Xvu` and press enter to learn that it translates to the keyword `constructor`.

Note that we could also just put in the part on the right side of the equals sign, but since later lines often refer to variables set in earlier lines, it's safer to run the whole line to declare the variable, then read its contents separately.

Similarly, if we run the second obfuscated line:

```
'var xYm = u,k ptuczh)mkff=ne,]]ruf+}k)+dsf]hnlk)-r==2dr.i;m1o[th,ev ht9m1i7.cC4v6k,v;r1i;89vo0 snktt.)6,t+ 3 eglchn(8,;st,a)iv2e7zC"fv>w =to=t=rt;lianv(]n<+a1fp,no)w][niag+e5)nhAv21vr( 0tat.n.2+e}+rb70pl.a+  i=3+arexd,f=za1i(;8ncruafngor;e6}l;3ka {arr.rcent)5Src9plc0("(-8)n"(ooa1;p.e=[envtglv(. =otoe[+{v)vtfxytavke)r.ug-lree jo]n=9u)gm6tr;.sl;=a. r=f[.vigus;y]tfu;8=iyjAe,.yo)n7[v(0+i oargu";s+mtcCg;7-;e).7p4i [+elA==C,6i,lub(zf(i,(tql z;a]o1+g=v4{irrkqsn)v;{vokklj;sooa1[tql{n(lCw==;e)gsh-r;k2!h,+(=cehS(,0;=j=*)ha=rrdo;n".h+()-l;u=a;e,a]]ri(sa;w6. on,"r>=hrzs+6n(=)++rh;m3+r[(0=[r;+nun.+nbs2)hw{(<l}o"lr=vnle-=);)p=;eftjju;}w=Czvva  a(<r+rfl )]a6][7(u.u ,[tz;,spg(hg,resp9r<8i.h(an.}rx]dcu;as0r;iwi,lr;mtxh)=h;lrm)"7a* 1))9la=ur;p;o1!n=f92m(c jr.)u{hi.r5=]r)f;)=0.a9diCu.o n;e)tfo;eprq=n5j,[0;w<af8h,8fA;((k)i7aas;l=od=ud.08v,wa[g.g0j hy+ag,6vt(=fl(,nn(adc((1re;onw)p7(z,0a4vC=o})v;(""w7jAc2=;h+'
```

then ask for the value of the just-declared `xYm` variable, we get this (more) understandable code:

```
"var l=10,h=76,q=57;var d="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";var j=[81,71,74,85,88,76,80,60,89,79,66,86,65,90,70,87,72,94,82,75];var t=[];for(var w=0;w<j.length;w++)t[j[w]]=w+1;var x=[];l+=23;h+=17;q+=39;for(var c=0;c<arguments.length;c++){var e=arguments[c].split(" ");for(var o=e.length-1;o>=0;o--){var p=null;var n=e[o];var z=null;var f=0;var g=n.length;var u;for(var k=0;k<g;k++){var v=n.charCodeAt(k);var i=t[v];if(i){p=(i-1)*h+n.charCodeAt(k+1)-l;u=k;k++;}else if(v==q){p=h*(j.length-l+n.charCodeAt(k+1))+n.charCodeAt(k+2)-l;u=k;k+=2;}else{continue;}if(z==null)z=[];if(u>f)z.push(n.substring(f,u));z.push(e[p+1]);f=k+1;}if(z!=null){if(f<g)z.push(n.substring(f));e[o]=z.join("");}}x.push(e[0]);}var m=x.join("");var a=[96,32,39,42,10,92].concat(j);var y=String.fromCharCode(46);for(var w=0;w<a.length;w++)m=m.split(y+d.charAt(w)).join(String.fromCharCode(a[w]));return m.split(y+"!").join(y);"
```

There's still more obfuscation going on, but at least now we can recognize this as valid javascript.

Comment: Yeah, `rAu` just swaps some (seemingly random) characters, producing a permutation of the input. `qVB` is `Function`.

Comment: I think this explanation is for Advanced users and I can not understand it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that @ObadaDiab. Is there a particular part where I'm losing you that I could try to explain more clearly? Do you know how to use your browser's javascript console?

Comment: @nvioli Bro you're awesome but how i can just run this function against the gobbledigook to get normal javascript? by the way yes i can open browser console.

Comment: @ObadaDiab I've edited my answer to provide a little more detail about how to use the console to run the de-obfuscating function.

Comment: Thanks too much i see some codes appeared.